# How to filter the PBD databank for "single-domain proteins with full length 3D-structures solved"

Tags: proteins

I am trying to reproduce a machine learning model that has been developed [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/842336v1). As one of the datasets, they use single-domain proteins with full length 3D-structures solved. Since I don't have a background in biology, I am not sure how to filter the [PDB databank](https://www.rcsb.org/) for these kind of proteins. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for the [bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com). If I were you, I would take a look at the [ftp/download section](https://www.rcsb.org/pages/download/ftp) of the PDB and see if the documenation for that let's you figure out the appropriate filters. It may be necessary to downlaod the full pdb & filter then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about bioinformatics rather than biology. Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site for descriptions of what is (and is not) a good fit for this site. Thanks! 